# How to implement A/B dual copy scheme partitioning?

Tags: embedded-linux, stm32, yocto

I am trying to implement A+B dual copy scheme partition on my Avenger96 board. I am using Yocto build system and also `.wks` file to create partitions. My `.wks` file:

```
part fsbl1 --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot-spl.stm32" --part-name "fsbl1" --ondisk mmcblk --align 1 --size 256k
part fsbl2 --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot-spl.stm32" --part-name "fsbl2" --ondisk mmcblk --align 1 --size 256k
part ssbl --source rawcopy --sourceparams="file=u-boot.itb" --part-name "ssbl" --ondisk mmcblk --align 1 --size 2M
part / --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label root_A --part-name "rootfs_A" --align 4096 --use-uuid --active --size 3G
part /rootfsB --source rootfs --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=ext4 --label root_B --part-name "rootfs_B" --align 4096 --use-uuid --size 3G

bootloader --ptable gpt
```

And I am able to build `.wic.xz` image and copied image to SD. It created 2 rootfs partitions.

But when I boot using this SD card, I could see both partitions are mounted. For example, there is also `/dev/root` which refers to current active partition `/dev/mmcblk0p4` and also `/dev/mmcblk0p5` (/rootfsB) when I do `df -h`

```
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                 5.0G      1.1G      3.6G  23% /
devtmpfs                469.7M         0    469.7M   0% /dev
tmpfs                   502.2M         0    502.2M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   502.2M      9.6M    492.5M   2% /run
tmpfs                   502.2M         0    502.2M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                   502.2M         0    502.2M   0% /tmp
tmpfs                   502.2M     16.0K    502.1M   0% /var/volatile
/dev/mmcblk0p5            5.0G      1.1G      3.6G  23% /rootfsB
tmpfs                   100.4M         0    100.4M   0% /run/user/0
```

And boot messages also show:

```
Mounting /rootfsB...
         Starting Start psplash boot splash screen...
[  OK  ] Mounted /rootfsB.
```

Also doing `mount` from linux user-space results in:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p4 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=480932k,nr_inodes=120233,mode=755)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=666)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /var/volatile type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mmcblk0p5 on /rootfsB type ext4 (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=102840k,mode=700)
```

Is this the expected behavior for A+B type partitioning?

Can anyone please let me know what could be the issue and how to resolve it?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually what I would expect. You want to boot from the "active" (A) partition, but you also want to be able to update the "passive" (B) partition. After you updated the "passive" (B) partition you typically tell the bootloader to try to boot from it. If that works (B) becomes the "active" partition and (A) the "passive" one.

Comment: Hello @robert.berger, thanks for the update. But when I update the passive partition (`/dev/mmcblk0p5` in my case) and when I do `df -h` I don't see my passive partition (`/dev/mmcblk0p4`) as mounted. I expected to see `/dev/mmcblk0p4` in the file system disk space statistics table (`df -h`) as mounted on `/`. I am bit confused why `/dev/mmcblk0p4` is not mounted.

Comment: (A) is active, (B) is passive. You update (B) and instruct the bootloader to mount (B) as your root partition instead of (A) and reboot. Then you should see what you expect.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do. I am using SWUpdate framework and choosing updated partition is part of SWUpdate right?. I have mentioned `rootfspart` in `sw-description` along with image name. And set `setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single\0"` in `boot.cmd`. But still something is missing I feel.

Comment: What does `cat /proc/cmdline` return?

Comment: `root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single root=/dev/mmcblk0p5 rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single0` is the output of `cat /proc/cmdline`. I don't know why there are 2 entries for `root`  variable.

Comment: I assume this is from a Linux shell. I'm impressed that it was able to boot with that. Apparently, something is wrong in your u-boot environment. Normally Linux user space tools should modify your u-boot environment.

Comment: It's using `boot.scr` script to load u-boot environment. I have set `setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single\0"` in `boot.cmd`. But I have also modified the u-boot config file `stm32mp1.h` and added `"bootargs=root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single\0" \` in `stm32mp1.h` also. Can this be the issue here with 2 times setting `bootargs`?

Comment: Hello @robert.berger, when I use SWUpdate to install updates, swupdate is successful but after reboot, it is still using old partition to boot. Is the .wks file used to create dual rootfs partition is wrong? I have attached .wks file to original post. I have set `--active` only to `part / ...` which is `dev/mmcblk0p4`. But I am able to switch partitions from u-boot environment. For example, in u-boot env, I can set `setenv rootfspart 5` and boot. Then it uses partition `/dev/mmcblk0p5` to boot.

Comment: There is no need to modify the u-boot environment twice. The .h file contains the default environment and the scr file can be used to modify things on the default environment.

Comment: Does this help? https://afterhourscoding.wordpress.com/2020/07/26/integrating-swupdate-with-u-boot/

Comment: Changes I did:  I have set `setenv bootargs "${bootargs} root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single\0"` in boot.cmd. Removed `"bootargs=root=/dev/mmcblk0p${rootfspart} rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single\0"`  in stm32mp1.h. Now `cat /proc/cmdline` returns only ` root=/dev/mmcblk0p5 rdinit=/bin/kinit rw rootwait single0`. I can even switch partitions from U-boot env by setting `rootfspart`. But when I use SWUpdate, I get update and installation successful but after re-boot in u-boot env when I check with `printenv rootfspart` it still uses old partition.

Comment: Also during boot after SWUpdate update, I encounter: `[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Star…progress communication helper.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device ▒▒2-b01d-4972-b914-c86e1e777f2a.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /rootfsB.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[  OK  ] Stopped Dispatch Password …ts to Console Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Stopped Forward Password R…uests to Wall Directory Watch.`

Comment: You might want to talk to the people on the swupdate list: https://groups.google.com/g/swupdate

Comment: I have posted the issue few days back, but no update from them.